# Where should i save extension data for me be available to retrieve these when I update the extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing an extension in VSCode that allow users to have theirs bookmarks, I save the file in the `context.extensionPath` but when I update the extension I lose that file because now the new version of the extension is installed in another folder.

Is there a way to maintain the same folder, or a standard folder to save extension data in VSCode? If not where should I save it? Or maybe there is a way to retrieve it and copy it to the new extension folder from the last version folder?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. There is a standard folder that accomplishes the task of saving extension key value data. As the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext) says, if you want to save key value data you should use the **`globalStoragePath`** folder.

This folder is not created by default so you have to do it the first time you want to save something there.